# Code automation for multiple variables with incrementing suffix

Tags: python, dataframe

On continuation from my first thread here [Code that creates variables, and increments its suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923835/code-that-creates-variables-and-increments-its-suffix)

So I already have a list called polygons

I am now trying to automate the code for the 10000 polygons (code for two polygons shown below as example). This code works fine if I were to do it manually for 10000 polygons but I am having issues automating it for 10K polygons

```
### Polygon 1 
def checkPolygon1(row):
    point = Point((row['X']), (row['Y']))
    return polygon1.contains(point)

#Apply fn to each row of dataframe (datacopy)
datacopy.apply(checkPolygon1, axis=1)

#Create new variable InPolygon1 in data if X, Y in shapely file 
datacopy['InPolygon1'] = datacopy.apply(checkPolygon1, axis=1)



### Polygon 2
def checkPolygon2(row):
    point = Point((row['X']), (row['Y']))
    return polygon2.contains(point)

datacopy.apply(checkPolygon2, axis=1)
#Create new variable InPolygon2 in data if X, Y in shapely file 
datacopy['InPolygon2'] = datacopy.apply(checkPolygon2, axis=1)
```

The idea is to have a dataframe with 10000 variables so InPolygon1, InPolygon2...InPolygon10000

Some of my attempts:
So to start with, I am trying to create another list that takes

```
polygons[0].contains(point), 
polygons[1].contains(point)...polygons[10000].contains(point)
```

But I am not able to correctly create it.

```
    def checkPolygon(row):
    point = Point((row['X']), (row['Y']))
    return point

    nextpolygons = []  
    def check():
        for i in range(0,2):  #actual range(0,10000)
            nextpolygons.append(polygons[i].contains(checkPolygon(row)))  

    check()   #NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

My idea is that after this list is correctly defined, I will try to automate the portions below:

```
datacopy.apply(checkPolygon1, axis=1)
datacopy['InPolygon1'] = datacopy.apply(checkPolygon1, axis=1)
```

Any ideas on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use the preview to check that your post is properly formatted so we can read it. I've edited this one for you (pending approval).

Comment: Why don't you post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE CR is for improviding the style of working code, not fixing code that gets an error.

Comment: Where is `row` defined in the `check()` function?

Comment: So I added some code def checkPolygon(row): portion in my original post...it still doesnt seem to automate it. I may be missing out on something..